# Wiremock - Record/Playback via forward proxy

Tags: wiremock

I am trying to use wiremock (standalone for now) to record/playback all requests made to an external SaaS system. However, I am trying through a corporate network where all requests need to be proxied.

The real request is:

```
curl -v -k --proxy "mycompany.proxy:81111" "https://api.thirdparty.com/api/v1/soap?wsdl"
```

which returns a result

From the Wiremock documentation, I have tried the following config:

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.21.0.jar --https-port 443 --record-mappings --proxy-all="https://api.thirdparty.com" --preserve-host-header --proxy-via="http://mycompany.proxy:81111" --verbose --print-all-network-traffic
```

However, I can't seem to get the same response back when using Wiremock.

If I try to hit Wiremock on HTTPS...

```
curl -v -k "https://localhost:443/api/v1/soap?wsdl"

* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   0 
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: 
ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/path/to/gitbash/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
 } [5 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
 } [512 bytes data]
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:--     
 0* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:443
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:--     0
 * Closing connection 0
 curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:443
```

and on the wiremock console....

```
    2019-02-06 13:00:08.017 Problem decoding network traffic
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.trafficlistener.ConsoleNotifyingWiremockNetworkTrafficListener.incoming(ConsoleNotifyingWiremockNetworkTrafficListener.java:40)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServer$NetworkTrafficListenerAdapter.incoming(JettyHttpServer.java:435)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.NetworkTrafficSelectChannelEndPoint.notifyIncoming(NetworkTrafficSelectChannelEndPoint.java:125)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.NetworkTrafficSelectChannelEndPoint.fill(NetworkTrafficSelectChannelEndPoint.java:48)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:516)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:240)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If, I try to hit wiremock with http...

```
$ curl -v -k "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/soap?wsdl"
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/v1/soap?wsdl HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
<
{ [95 bytes data]
 100    84    0    84    0     0   2709      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5600
No response could be served as there are no stub mappings in this WireMock instance.
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wiremock documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/), you can programmaticaly set to target the end API via a proxy (but not via JSON).

> ### Proxying via another proxy server
>
> If you’re inside a network that only permits HTTP traffic out to the
>   internet via an opaque proxy you might wish to set up proxy mappings
>   that route via this server. This can be configured programmatically by
>   passing a configuration object to the constructor of WireMockServer or
>   the JUnit rules like this:

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options()
    .proxyVia("proxy.mycorp.com", 8080)
);
```